# Enabling installer rights using installer created through Wix

Tags: xml, wix, wix3.5

I have created an installer using Wix on a dialog page i am running as an admin i want a checkbox that if checked should install for the current user(admin) and all other users in the system , is it possible using Wix?

And how would the installer checks the rights that the current user has?

For example if i am installing on a standard user account then how would the installer would know what account is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As I understand, u need to have a special gui window for the checkboxes? U could [see here](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited) for a good tutorial.

Another ur problem is to check current user and his rights? u need to use some standard env variables. Use

```
    <Condition Message="Message text">Privileged</Condition>
```

to check admin rights. If this condition is passing - u r running as an administrator.

For checking the current user, use  LogonUser env variable. E.g. u can create a custom dialog, where u could check whether it needs to be installed "for all" users or just for current. next step - checking for admin rights.

And.. use more google...

Comment: Is it possible to check in the registry of the system regarding which user is running , if yes please let me know how?

Comment: @eddie Why u need to take the CurrentUserName exactly from registry? it is not so trivial.. just take from wix?!

Comment: :I guess registry would be convienient

Comment: I guess, registry would be more headackable =) just use what is simple now, even more it is possible and not so inconvinient =)

Comment: moreover, it is usefull to look at a verbose log of installing. use msiexec -i *.msi -l*v *.log   At the end, it will be many properties (variables) that also could be used!

Comment: @eddie Why do you need to invent a wheel when WiX, Windows Installer indeed, provides you the information you want: the user name, admin/regular user, OS version number, etc. By trying to obtain this information from the registry you would make your life complicated and you would create a bad MSI package. See the [full list of Windows Installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905)

Comment: <Condition Message="Message text">Privileged</Condition>:Where exacltyly do i need to put tthis statement i have a condition as when user selects a radiobutton and click on next the condition must be checked

Comment: @eddie U need to use it in ur custom action in the begining. E.g.

     <CustomAction Id="" trololo...>
       <Condition Message="">Priveleged</Condition>
     </CustomAction>